# Custom Plugin CSS: Can't update them!

Tags: css

I have made a plugin for my website which has custom CSS Styles. I don't know why, the styles, once the plugin is activated, they look normal, as expected. But when I update the plugin's .css file, it always looks like as the 1st version of the .css file. I tried to clear cache with WP Rocket and on Chrome, and it doesn't work. But when I go with Incognito Mode, it charges the most recent version of the .css file.

How can I change that?

For example, for a custom template for my theme, I do something like:

```
<?php 
function picaronia_dashboard_remove_all_styles() { 
 if (is_page_template('dashboard.php')) { 
  global $wp_styles; 
  foreach ($wp_styles->registered as $item) { 
   wp_dequeue_style($item->handle);
  } 
 } 
} 
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'picaronia_dashboard_remove_all_styles');

function write_picaronia_dashboard_styles() { 
 if (is_page_template('dashboard.php')) { 
  $src = get_site_url() . "/wp-content/plugins/dashboard-de-   picaronia/css/frontend.css"; 
  wp_enqueue_style('picaronia-dashboard-styles', $src);
  wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts-picaronia-dashboard', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
 }
} 
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'write_picaronia_dashboard_styles'); 
?>
```

It seems like the plugin's CSS styles file remain in caché and it doesn't update.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your browser multiple times? Clearing your browser cache and cookies should do the trick.

Comment: have look on this post - https://wordimpress.com/wordpress-css-and-js-cache-busting/

Answer (score 0):

It's only a cache issue, you need to clean your browser and/or server cache.